# Constructing a separable space that is not hereditarily separable.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

The construction that I had in mind was:

Let $X$ be an uncountable space. We'll assume it has just one countable dense subset $E$. Let points $p_{1},p_{2}\in X\setminus E$ such that every open set containing either of the two points contains some or all points $a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}\in E$. Then the space $X-\{ a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}\}$ won't have a countable dense subset, as $E-\{ a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}\}$ won't have $p_{1},p_{2}$ in its closure.

Am I making too many assumptions?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The Sorgenfrey plane is separable, but has a discrete uncountable subspace.

Answer (score 3):

This is not so much a construction, as a vague idea, maybe. I suppose you want a separable but not hereditarily separable space?

A simple example $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$, in the included point topology with respect to $0$. So $O$ is open iff it is empty or it contains $0$. Then $\{0\}$ is dense, so $X$ is separable, but $X\setminus\{0\}$ is discrete in itself, so not separable. But $X$ is not even $T_1$.

Nicer examples: the $S \times S$, where $S$ is the Sorgenfrey line: this is separable, but has the set $D = \{(x, -x): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ as a closed and discrete subspace. Or any uncountable product like $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$, which is separable, but the set of all points with exactly one value equal to $1$ and all others to $0$, is again discrete as a subspace (and uncountable), so we have another non-separable subspace.

Comment: An eaiser example is that a space $X$ with finite completement topology on an uncountable set.

Comment: That space is hereditarily separable: every (infinite) subspace is also a finite complement space, so also separable. The poster wanted (I think) a separable but not hereditarily separable space.

Answer (score 1):

This may not warrant an answer, but here are couple observations.

1. You will have to be careful in your assumption of "just one countable dense subset" since adding any point to a countable dense set will result in another.  (Of course, a countable discrete space really *does* have only one countable dense subset, but a separable, not hereditarily separable space must be uncountable.)
2. It is not clear why $E_0 = ( E \setminus \{ a_1 , \ldots , a_n \} ) \cup \{ p_1 , p_2 \}$ couldn't be a countable dense subset of $X \setminus \{ a_1 , \ldots , a_n \}$.

Comment: Regarding point 2: Because all open sets containing $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ contained only points $a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}$ from $E$. Hence, in $X-\{ a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}\}$, no open set containing $p_{1}$ or $p_{2}$ will contain any point from $E$. This shows $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are not limit points of $E-\{ a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}\}$

Comment: Regarding point 1: True. Maybe then the condition could be there's a descending sequence of countable dense subsets, and the set under consideration is the intersection of all these sets. Let this intersection be $E$. The rest of the argument follows.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: re first comment: please re-read my second point. Since $p_1 , p_2 \in E_0$, then clearly $p_1 , p_2 \in \overline{ E_0}$.  re second comment: Again, there are going to be _many_ such descending sequences, and no immediate reason to prefer one over the others.

Comment: I might be way off, but I feel if $E-\{ a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}\}$ is not dense, and $A$ is a countable subset of $X$ such that $E\subset A$, then $A-\{ a_{1},a_{2}\dots a_{n}\}$ too can't be dense. Hence, we have a definite advantage in considering only the intersection of all such nested countabe dense subsets...don't we?

Comment: But I'll give your observations a lot more thought before voicing further doubts. Thanks